# CRTP base constructor crashes because child is not constructed

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, crtp

I have classes which are autogenerated but I want to enable end users to add custom member functions and constructors.

My approach is to use a CRTP base class which has no member variables just functions.

The problem lies with the constructor. If I define a constructor in my CRTP I cannot correctly access the child as it is not constructed yet as the child classes constructor only gets called after the CRTP base is constructed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<class Child>
struct Foo {
  Foo(std::string i) {
    // Childs constructor is not run yet.
    std::cout << static_cast<Child&>(*this).d.size(); // Prints trash
    static_cast<Child&>(*this).d = i; // Segfault here
    (void) i;
  }
};

// Cannot change this class.
struct Bar : Foo<Bar> {
  using base_t = Foo<Bar>;
  using base_t::base_t;
  std::string d;
};


int main()
{
  Bar bar("asdgasdgsag");
  std::cout << "bar.d: " << bar.d << std::endl;
}
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Yep, that is clear so far.

Comment: This is a well-known problem. You'd have the same issue with virtual functions and inheritance. Not solvable, constructor can't use stuff from derived class.

Comment: You need 2-phase initialization. Construct first, then finish off in a separate initialization function.

Comment: Problem solved! The second phase can be done by a temporary bound to a constructor parameter with a default argument !!

Comment: @SergeyA But the destructor of a constructor argument can do it!

Comment: Why don't you initialize members of the child class in the child constructor where it belongs?  - A base class with no members usually do not need any user supplied constructors. On the other hand, if all child classes derived from the same base have the same members, why don't you move those members to the base class? Then you can (and must) initialize those members in the base constructor.

Comment: @CAF: Because the code is autogenerated for every class but every class should have a custom constructor.

Comment: If you find yourself writing a lot of classes that all have "the same" member, consider moving this member to their common base claas. In your case all children of `Foo` are expected to have `std::string d;` member. It is natural and proper to move it to `Foo`.

Answer (score 8):

Your base constructor can't do things with the child class. At all. The latter hasn't been constructed yet.

CRTP allows other member functions of `Foo` to do so, but that's about it.

There's no "quick fix" within the design you've come up with. You can either add a `Init`-like function to `Foo` to do this stuff later (and invoke it from the child's ctor), or (ideally) rethink your approach.

It's a bit odd that you can't modify the child class but are adding things to the `Base` — that's not how inheritance is supposed to be done, and it seems like you're trying to use CRTP to hack around that, but have found out why this is not a valid hack.

Without knowing what you're trying to accomplish I can't be more precise than that.

Maybe a factory function can help you? Or inherit from `Bar`.

Comment: I have classes which are autogenerated so I can add the CRTP base by changing the generator. The end user can then provide a CRTP base and define some type trait specialization to properly associate the CRTP base with its desired type.
I cannot use inheritance the other way around as I might get a `std::vector<Bar>` whose elements I want to treat as `Foo`.

Comment: @AndreasPasternak If you can change the generator in that manner, surely you can change it in another :) Whatever that `Foo<Bar>` ctor is doing to the `Bar` subobject should be in the `Bar` ctor instead, period!

Answer (score -1):

There is a solution. It is not UB according to the C++17 standard, but UB for C++14. It is not clean neither.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#if __cpp_inheriting_constructors < 201511
  #error "Not supported."
#endif

template<class Child>
struct post_construct{
    Child* constructed;
    std::string i;
    ~post_construct(){
        constructed->d=std::move(i);
    }
};


template<class Child>
struct Foo {
  Foo(std::string i,post_construct<Child>&& m=post_construct<Child>{}) {
    m.constructed = static_cast<Child*>(this);
    m.i = std::move(i);
  }
};

// Cannot change this class.
struct Bar : Foo<Bar> {
  using base_t = Foo<Bar>;
  using base_t::base_t;
  std::string d;
};


int main()
{
  Bar bar("asdgasdgsag"); //temporary materialization here
                          //then temporary destroyed at end of full-expression
  std::cout << "bar.d: " << bar.d << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a02c042fb8987441)

[Assembly code and compiler checks](https://godbolt.org/z/Ky0AR6)

Comment: Using a "hidden" parameter on the constructor is terribly confusing and inflexible. Clever though.

Comment: This is still UB. I do not see how it solves anything. `Child` is  constructed only after it'is constructor is terminated.

Comment: @SergeyA This is UB in [c++14](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/class.inhctor#8). Not in [c++17](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.inhctor.init#1). As the last time our opinion diverged, the reason was a semantic change in the standard.

Comment: @SergeyA The trick relies on the sequencing and lifetime of the base ctor's default argument stretching into the derived subobject's burgeoning lifetime. Personally I'm not convinced the linked standard passage is relevant but what do I know

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This was introduced in the standard by [P01361R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0136r1.html). It is not yet supported by MSVC, but it is supported by gcc and clang. If you look at this assembly [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ChJo5r), the call to the destructor of `post_construct` is performed after the call to the default constructor of `derived_member`.